# How to make custom dots in owl carousel?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I have implemented custom prev next buttons(i ommit css styles for prev next buttons), but havent dots. Who know what is mistake I did?

```css
// owl.carousel.css

.owl-controls {
    text-align: center;
}
.owl-controls .owl-dot {
    display: inline-block;
}
.owl-controls .owl-dot span {
    background-color: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    width: 12px;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=500);/*IE7 fix*/
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.owl-controls .owl-dot.active span, .owl-controls .owl-dot:hover span {
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      loop:true,
      margin:10,
      nav:true,
      navText: ["<img src='prevArrow.png'>","<img src='nextArrow.png'>"],
      responsive:{
         0:{
             items:1
         },
         600:{
             items:1
         },
         1000:{
             items:1
         }
      }
   })
  });
 </script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
   <img src="lylka.png" alt="">
   <img src="lylka.png" alt="">
   <img src="lylka.png" alt="">
   <img src="lylka.png" alt="">
   <img src="lylka.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use option dotsContainer, but sometimes it works oddly.

For example

```
<div id='carousel' class='owl-carousel'> 
  <div class='item'></div> 
  <div class='item'></div> 
  <div class='item'></div> 
</div>
<ul id='carousel-custom-dots' class='owl-dots'> 
  <li class='owl-dot'><!-- Anything in here --></li> 
  <li class='owl-dot'></li> 
  <li class='owl-dot'></li> 
</ul>
```

Next include this inside of your options object.

```
owl.owlCarousel({
  dotsContainer: '#carousel-custom-dots'
});
```

The following tells Owl Carousel 2 to go to a slide based on the index of the dot that was clicked.

```
$('.owl-dot').click(function () {
  owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
});
```

That should be all you need to get custom dots up and going with Owl Carousel 2.

via <s>http://derickruiz.com/owl-carousel-custom-dots</s>

Comment: Try to put relevant code fragments into answer itself.

Comment: Trying this, i'm getting a 'owl is not defined' error message. Any idea as to how this is possible?

Comment: @IdrisDopicoPeña You should get the element for which you have initialized the Owl Carousel and pass the trigger like that:
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel().trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem in this way:

HTML code

```
<section id="slider" class="content-slider row">
<div class="col-8 owl-carousel slide-cnt">
    <div class="slide"><h3>TITOLO</h3></div>
    <div class="slide"><h3>TITOLO</h3></div>
    <div class="slide"><h3>TITOLO</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 dots-cnt">
    <ul class="elenco-articoli">
        <li>Titolo</li>
        <li>Titolo</li>
        <li>Titolo</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var owl;
owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 600,
    nav:true,
    navText: ["<",">"],
    dots:false,
    items:1
});
jQuery('.elenco-articoli').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [jQuery(this).index(), 300]);
});
```

This work for me.

If you want you can elaborate on: https://codepen.io/vbeetlejuice/pen/dRaero

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
   .owl-dots button i {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="testimonial_slider owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item" data-dot="<button><i></i><img src='images/testimonial-1.jpg' alt='' class='img-fluid' /></button>">
        <div class="testimonial-dec">
            <h4>Aklima The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections Bonorum et Malorum original.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-name mt-4">
            <p class="border-bottom d-inline-block"><span class="d-inline-block text-uppercase text-dark">AKLIMA</span>  - COO, AMERIMAR ENTERPRISES, INC.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.testimonial_slider').owlCarousel({
    loop:false,
    margin:32,
    nav:false,
    dots: true,
    items:1,
    mouseDrag: false,
    dotsData: true,
});
```

[enter image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR70c.png)